# Cant ping or connect to computers on my LAN though win 10 VPN server

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I need to work on my home desktop computer from my country house. So I setup a VPN server on my home server. A windows 10 machine, following this guide.

https://pureinfotech.com/setup-vpn-server-windows-10/

I can connect, and I get a IP. But I cant ping or connect to my computers on the LAN.

To tings that stand out when doing "ipconfig". The VPN connection gateway is blank and the subnet mask is 255.255.255.255 instead of the normal 255.255.255.0

Also I can ping my gateway (Router) at 191.168.1.1. and browse to its http admin UI. Thats the only thing I can ping and connect to when connected to the VPN

Comment: See if this answer helps you:   https://serverfault.com/questions/34779/vpn-with-wrong-subnet-mask

Comment: Also make sure the local IP of the home machine is the Windows 10 IP address. It may want to be a static IP on your home router.

Comment: Ot sounds to me like the Windows server is not forwarding packets, but it could also be that you have the same IP address ranges on both connections, or more likely a NAT issue on the Windows server. What does a traceroute to one of the unreachable devices show, what are the IP ranges on each network and have you considered running the VPN server on the router instead?

Comment: "have you considered running the VPN server on the router instead? " .... I use a VPN Router and access my home network that way from anywhere I happen to be. That allows access to the complete home subnet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. It was some random events that made me think it didn't work. For some reason you can't access the VPN server host and that was the computer that i tried to ping and access. I also tried to ping my workstation but it did not respond to ping requests not even when i connect directly to the LAN. When I tried to connect with remote desktop to the workstation it worked. So everything was working all the time :) i have a router that was shipped with my ISP and it have 1 gigabit full duplex on the WAN port so i haven't bothered replacing it, it has no VPN feature